# NSWindow, how not to be part of a screenshot?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

My Cocoa app displays a transparent window on the screen, but when the user tries to take a screenshot using Mac OS X's built-in screen capture key with the option of selecting full windows (Command-Shift-4, then Space Bar), my window gets highlighted as part of the possible windows to capture.

How can I tell my Window or App not to allow this? My Window already refuses to be the Main Window or Key Window through `-canBecomeKeyWindow` and `-canBecomeMainWindow` both returning NO, but this still happens.

The Window is also at the `NSModalPanelWindowLevel` and `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel` does the same thing.

Comment: At one point, OpenGL applications couldn't have their screenshots taken this way. Don't know if that has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that every window is eligible for screenshots, even the desktop, dock and menu bar, which are special windows. You can even take a screenshot of the Exposé overlay window itself. This leads me to believe that there is no way to do this.

I suppose you could hook the Command+Shift+4 key event and hide the window, but that key combo is user-definable, so it is subject to change.

Comment: Yep, that's what I've figured. Not much I can do it seems... thanks for answering!